# Layout-xlarge folder not working

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'am testing my app in **xlarge** devices, so I'm using the 10.1" emulator. I created the *layout-xlarge* folder and made specific *XML* files for these devices. But when I run the project, the emulator runs the layout (default) folder, and not the **layout-xlarge**.

What could be wrong?

Comment: can you post the setting of that emulator.

Comment: Here is:
Target: Android 4.1.2
Skin: 1024x600

Comment: What settings do you have in the mainfest for that particular activity?

Comment: I have this:

`<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
            android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />`

Comment: @niarb i mean the whole settings not just part of it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I can't comment everything because is too long, but here is everything (without the activities):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tcms.aquabalance"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />`

Comment: @niarb no not the manifest the emulator settings is what I mean, Also you can edit your post above and paste it there. Go to `Window -> Android virtual device -> click the device and details`

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin here is

Emulator definitions:

CPU/ABI: Arm 
Target: Android 4.1.2
Skin: 1024x600
hw.dpad: no
hw.acelerometer: yes
hw.device.name: 7in WSVGA (tablet)
vm.heapSize: 16
skin.dynamic: no
hw.device.manufactuer: Generic

Comment: @niarb in the `hw.lcd.density` what does it says?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I don't have that detail

Comment: @niarb yes you do drag the window to maximize it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Wow, i'am having the noob feeling. Here is:

hw.lcd.density : 160dp

Answer (score 1):

```
 hw.lcd.density : 160dp
```

That is not a `xhdpi` but `mdpi`

as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for it:

```
Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline density.)
```

**solution:**

Click the **edit** button in the right side and on the `Device` part you can then choose the device you want with its corresponding `DPI` measurement

Comment: Thanks, I edited the layout-xlarge to layout-ldpi, and still the same. It's using the layout (default) folder.

Comment: @niarb sorry its `mdpi` typo.. :))

Comment: thank you! It works! I didn't know that although the device has a xlarge size, the xlarge folder couldn't work, so thanks for the tip.